# Android - 2 aar libraries don't work together

Tags: android, android-ndk, aar

Consider having 2 different `.aar` library files – LibA.aar and LibB.aar. LibA.aar contains `.so` files for architectures `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86`. LibB.aar contains `.so` files for `armeabi` and `x86`. If I use these libraries separately(!), then there is no issue. However, when I use both libraries together, then I get `UnsatisfiedLinkError` saying that I miss some `.so` file.

I noticed that if I create a folder `armeabi-v7a` for LibB.aar and put into it a missing `.so` file copied from `armeabi` folder, then the issue dissapears.

Another temporal solution was to add to the gradle file:

```
ndk{
    abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
}
```

**My question**: Is it a correct way to deal with such an issue or there is a better approach? Is it possible to say to a library that use certain architectures? For example when we set a library in `build.gradle`:

```
compile(name: 'LibB', ext: 'aar') 
{
  // use some specific architecture, e.g "armeabi", "x86"
}
```

I hope I explain it clearly. Please, let me know in case you need addition information. Many thanks for any effort to help.

Comment: your application won't work on `armeabi-v7a`, if some libraries miss .so files of that architecture.It should not be OK to just copy file from `armeabi`.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko, But it is curious, why the app works if I use the libraries separately?

Comment: The reason might be that if there is one lib, then the app automatically targets the ABIs, supported by that lib. If it uses 2 libs, it tries to merge ABIs, and finds that one of the libraries is missing some ABIs, and warns you about that. As for me, adding `ndk{
    abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
}` is not a temporally, but a correct solution, which directly points to which ABIs are supported by the app

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko, exactly, that's what I was thinking about - automatic merging of JNI folders causes an issue.  Thank you.